# npm --save-dev reacts sripts fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I succesffully installed react js on my local server, and also created a new project. But every time I navigate to the project folder and try "npm start", I keep getting the erro npm --save-dev react scripts failed; missing start script."

Any help will be much appreciated.

Dane

Comment: Did you `npm install` the dependencies of your script?

Comment: what have you got defined in your `package.json` `{ "scripts"{ "start": ... }}`?